# Minicom and screen in background

Tags: tty, serial, minicom

I would like to log serial port output in background.

I use `screen` command for `minicom` to make sure minicom running on the background when I disconnect my ssh session. This actually works fine, but when I use screen with minicom, I am not able to use the minicom menu. When I press CTRL-Z A, screen just go to background. So I am not able to interact with minicom, also not able to close minicom.

Is there a way to make the minicom menu available with screen?

Or, is there any better way to log serial port in background?

Comment: *"I use screen command for minicom"* -- What???   What is *"in background"* supposed to mean?  Minicom has its own built-in logging capability to capture all input and output; is that what you need?

Comment: I need to run the logging unattended.  (So if I disconnected from ssh, logging is still running)

Answer (score 2):

Add `--metakey` to your `minicom` command line. It switches control key from `Ctrl+a` to `Alt` (in my case) for minicom and now `Ctrl+a d` work properly for screen detach.
ps. you can also turn on timestamp in minicom menu (N key).